# Bootstrap tab - how to refer to a seperate url template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I trying make a tab shows the active tab when clicked which I have successfully done. I want to link the content of another html template when the tab is clicked, but when I do so the tab "function" stopped working.

In my main URL I have the following code:

```
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="{%url 'Safety' %}">Safety</a></li>
  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="{%url 'Quality' %}">Quality</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried to

added the following:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
    <a href="{%url 'Safety' %}">
  </div>
</div>
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't confuse Django URL(pattern)s with views or templates. What you referred to as your “main URL” is a template, not a URL(pattern).

Secondly, the Bootstrap tabbed navigation is for manipulating HTML content that's already in the browser, that is, already rendered by the server (Django). You cannot “link” to another HTML/Django template; you link to URLs, not templates. You can, however, `include` a template in another one.

I'm going to go ahead and presume that you want to use Bootstrap's tabbed navigation in a main template, while keeping the component 'Safety' and 'Quality' templates in separate files. Then you should do something like:

```html
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="safety-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#safety-content">Safety</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="quality-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#quality-content">Quality</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="safety-content">
    {% include "safety.html" %}
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="quality-content">
    {% include "quality.html" %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note how this doesn't use the `{% url ... %}` Django template tag. Also, remember to replace `"safety.html"` and `"quality.html"` with the path to your 'Safety' and 'Quality' templates.

Comment: Thank you a very detailed explanation. It is correct what u have stated: that I want to keep the component Safety and Quality templates in separates files!:) 

For some reason, I cant include my Quality template and Safety template :(. I tried creating a new random template, and that template I can include:S

Comment: @JianGuiLi you're welcome! Since you seem new to Stack like me, let me share a friendly reminder to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if they address your question satisfactorily.